# How to create model class based response?

Tags: angular

I request data from server using service:

```
export class SearchService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getSearchCatalogs(): Observable<SearchCatalogs> {
        return this.http.get<SearchCatalogs>(`${environment.apiUrl}/catalogs`);
    }
}
```

It returns me response object:

```
export interface SearchCatalogs {
    controlStatus: ControlStatu[];
    state: State[];
    source: Source[];
    department: Department[];
}
```

I want to use this response in template, should I create class model based response with set/get for each object property?

```
class SearchCatalog {
    get controlStatus() {}
    set controlStatus(value: any) {}
    
    get state() {}
    set state(value: any) {}
}
```

I afraid case when there is not property, for example `department` when I pass it in template:

```
<app-control [data]="search.department">
<div *ngFor="search.department"></div>
```

Or another one.

How to do that properly in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make some of them optional, you will not face any problem if department is not present, change it to **department?:**

```
export interface SearchCatalogs {
 controlStatus: ControlStatu[];
 state: State[];
 source: Source[];
 department?: Department[];
}
```

and in your template use safe navigation

```
<app-control [data]="search?.department">
<div *ngFor="search?.department"></div>
```

You can create an ADAPTER too to convert your API response to your internal representation, you can take a look on **The Model-Adapter Pattern**:

- create a generic interface

  ```
  export interface Adapter<T> {
   adapt(itm: any): T;
  }
  ```
- create adapter inside your SearchCatalogs model file

  ```
  export class SearchCatalogs {
   constructor(){
    controlStatus: ControlStatu[];
    state: State[];
    source: Source[];
    department: Department[];
   }
  }

  ...
  @Injectable({
   providedIn: "root",
  })
  export class SearchCatalogsAdapter implements Adapter<SearchCatalogs > {
   adapt(itm: any): SearchCatalogs {
     return new SearchCatalogs(itm.controlStatus, itm.state, itm.source);
   }
  }
  ```
- update your service

  ```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private adapter: SearchCatalogsAdapter ) {}

  getSearchCatalogs(): Observable<SearchCatalogs> {
    return this.http.get<SearchCatalogs>(`${environment.apiUrl}/catalogs`)
    .pipe(
     map((data) => this.adapter.adapt(data))
    );
  }
  ```

Comment: What if I need to map data before displaying, I am talking about architecture approach more

Comment: a simple solution is to use rxjs map operator

Comment: or you can create an adapter

Comment: You forgot constructor here export class SearchCatalogs {}

Comment: What if yo use async here `<app-control [data]="search?.department | async">`? How to be if I use some async? It call the same time request

Comment: if your search is an observable it should be [data]="(search | async)?.department"